# Changing Focus in Input fields depending on what link was clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, focus

Im pretty new to jquery/JS so I hope some of you can help me.
I have a backend site with three links - each link showing to the same form, in order to make changes and save them to my frontend. I would like that based on what link I clicked, the focus should change to the correct input field. 
Here my Code:

```
        <main>
        <div class="main-table">
            <div class="border event clearfix">
                    <h2>Titel: <span>American Classics</span></h2> <a href="index.php?page=eventinfo&amp;action=edit">bearbeiten</a>
            </div>
            <div class="border event clearfix">
                    <h2>Datum: <span>19.07.2014</span></h2> <a href="index.php?page=eventinfo&amp;action=edit">bearbeiten</a>
            </div>
            <div class="border event clearfix">
                    <h2>Uhrzeit: <span>18:00</span></h2> <a href="index.php?page=eventinfo&amp;action=edit">bearbeiten</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

When clicking on them, I will be redirected to the following page:

```
 <main>
            <form action="" Method="POST">
                <a href="index.php?page=eventinfo">Zurück zur Eventinformation</a>
                <h2>Eventinformation bearbeiten</h2>
                <label for="title">Titel:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
                <br>
                <label for="date">Datum:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
                <br>
                <label for="time">Uhrzeit:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="time" id="time" name="time">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit-event" id="submit-event" value="Änderungen speichern">
            </form>
        </main>`
```

Peease notice that the coding is not finished yet, though i would really appreciate if someone could help me resolve my issue with the focus - based on JS or Jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Id In your url like `index.php?page=eventinfo&amp;action=edit#title`

and on the redirected page

```
var textbox=window.location.hash;
$(textbox).focus();
```